# A mountain of a mole hill?

Tags: java, algorithm, flood-fill

I am trying to solve https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/a-mountain-of-a-mole-hill following problem but I dont understand how to approach to this problem. below requirement of the problem

Moles have infested a 16x16 area.
The fences of your gardens are outlined on maps with |, + and - symbols.
The mole hills are represented by a lower-case o.
How many mole hills are in your gardens?

- Two parallel fences of the garden cannot touch (it wouldn't make sense).
- Garden space is filled with white space unless there is a mole hill. Other space is filled with dots unless there is a mole hill.
- Everything that touches the outside of the map and is not enclosed in fences is other space. A fence is always between garden space and other space.
- Mole hills cannot be on fences.

below initial code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
        }

        // Write an answer using System.out.println()
        // To debug: System.err.println("Debug messages...");

        System.out.println("answer");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would check if any `o` is surrounded by any `.` so it's not in a garden. This may be a starting point. Then, treat edge cases

Comment: If a line (String) does not contain a fence - skip it. If it does : find the index of the first fence and the index of the second fence. Count moles in between those indices.

Comment: @cOder can you explain what you mean with coding sample

Comment: @c0der I spot a questionable assumption of convex garden in your approach.

Comment: I assume that the shown code does not contain any of your own. So ....

Comment: This, as most questions which give a strong impression of being a blind homework dump, lacks focus on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. To improve have a look at the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and at [ask].

Comment: Since the question has been closed I'll suggest a path here, building on c0der's hint and on Yunnosch's valuable comment: consider one line at a time, skip everything until you meet a vertical fence, check everything for a mole hill until you meet another vertical fence, and so on (gardens may have strange shapes)

Comment: To speed things up you may probably ignore lines 0 and 15 (and symbols 0 and 15 on the remaining lines) cause a fence cannot be on the border of the map; and you may probably also skip lines 1 and 14 since at most they can contain horizontal (top and bottom) fences

Comment: @c0der how many mole hill there : `O|O|O|O|O` ? 2? 3? 5?

Comment: @Cid I am not sure that `O|O|O|O|O` represent a valid garden. If it does the algo needs to be adapted.

Comment: @c0der it's just a single line as you suggested to parse it line by line. I know a bit codingames and there are always such edge cases